# Set second monitor to use large cursor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, cursor

My second monitor is a TV across the room. It's impossible to see the cursor and I rely on keyboard shortcuts. Sometimes the cursor would be easier is there a way to enlarge it for the second monitor only?

Answer (score 0):

A simple command in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true
```

Allows you to tape the <kbd>Control</kbd> key and get a ripple effect around the mouse pointer:

[image: gnome locate mouse.gif]